# Retrieve a specific level level from a JSON object in Node.js

Tags: node.js, json

I have a two level JSON

```
{"Policy":    {
      "Channel": "online",
      "Credit Score": "20000",
      "Car":       [{
         "Age": "28",
         "AnnualMiles": "15000",
         "CarAge": "3",
         "Young Driver": "1"
      }
      ]
      
   }}
```

i am trying to change the json structure and only retrieve the root policy object from the JSON

```
let data = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(data)
    policy=data.Policy 
    console.log(policy)
```

The output that i am getting is the entire JSON basically, the result that i want is just the root level values :

```
{
"Channel": "online",
"Credit Score": "20000"
}
```

How do i only retrieve the root level in nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = {"Policy":    {
      "Channel": "online",
      "Credit Score": "20000",
      "Car":       [{
         "Age": "28",
         "AnnualMiles": "15000",
         "CarAge": "3",
         "Young Driver": "1"
      }
      ]
   }}

//Filter function for objects
Object.filter = (obj, predicate) => 
    Object.keys(obj)
          .filter( key => predicate(obj[key]) )
          .reduce( (res, key) => (res[key] = obj[key], res), {} );

//Exclude objects
let result = Object.filter(json.Policy, x => typeof x != "object")
console.log(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{
  Channel: "online",
  Credit Score: "20000"
}
```